# Bootstrap navbar-button do not vertical align center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bellow code to add a right button, which is "订阅按钮":

```
<!doctypoe html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">www.<strong>google</strong>.com</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="">课程</a></li>
            <li><a href="">博客</a></li>
            <li><a href="">手册</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm navbar-btn navbar-right">订阅课程</a>
        </div>      

    </nav>
    <div class="container" style="height:5000px;">  
        <div>
            <h1>title123</h1>
            <p>按时打算是多少对阿斯达方的方式斯蒂芬斯蒂芬按时打算</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

But however the button is not vertical align center, you can see my snapshot bellow:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: What exact version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested your code and it's not vertically centered in bootstrap versions 3.0.0-3.0.2 but centered in 3.0.3-3.3.7

I suspect you are using an old version of bootstrap. Upgrade?

Comment: I am bootstrap 3.0.2.